# Could not apply the stored configuration for the monitor

Tags: configuration, monitor

I'm using Nvidia 7300 gt and monitor-Acer V173w, on 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04.
Compiz and Emerald went well, but at the time of entry into the GUI, I always receive the message :
**"Could not apply the stored configuration for the monitor, could not find a suitable configuration of screens"**

Why do I always receive it, and what is wrong with the monitor configuration or pci-e is used?

[image]

```
root@dellph1-desktop:/# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1440 x 900, maximum 1440 x 900
default connected 1440x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900       50.0* 
   1024x768       51.0     58.0     59.0  
   1360x768       52.0     53.0  
   1152x864       54.0     55.0     56.0     57.0  
   960x600        60.0  
   960x540        61.0  
   896x672        62.0  
   840x525        63.0     64.0     65.0     66.0  
   832x624        67.0  
   800x600        68.0     69.0     70.0     71.0     72.0     73.0  
   800x512        74.0  
   720x450        75.0  
   680x384        76.0     77.0  
   640x512        78.0     79.0  
   640x480        80.0     81.0     82.0     83.0  
   576x432        84.0     85.0     86.0     87.0  
   512x384        88.0     89.0     90.0  
   416x312        91.0  
   400x300        92.0     93.0     94.0     95.0  
   320x240        96.0     97.0     98.0  
root@dellph1-desktop:/#
```

=== xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 260.19.29  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-04.nvidia.com)  Wed Dec  8 12:27:27 PST 2010


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: xconfig, VertRefresh source: xconfig
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer V173W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 7300 GT"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" " 1440x900_60 +0+0; 1280x1024 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "1440x900 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1440x900_75 +0+0; 1440x900 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 28):

Remove `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and the answer that was here not worked , haven't .config, but i fixed it

and this is the way that i did and it fixed it at me:

first i went to Ubuntu software center and deleted the last programs that i installed after first one restarted and no thing happened , second program was mono and i deleted it too

second step , i didn't restarted , i went to system settings , then i have choose displays and made rotation normal and chooded my built in display , 
just edit the options of it and if you have other displays can choose all in low or other

then I restarted , and all back okay

i think it was the program but also may be was the displays option, that fixed it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All I have to do is open Displays and press Apply
[image: Displays tool]

Now the configuration file `.config/monitors.xml` is re-written correctly!