# How do I get rid of this monitor error?

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, xorg

I have an Nvidia card and two monitors.

Every time I log in to Unity on Ubuntu 11.10, I get this error:

[image: x monitor error]

"Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors"

I have tried opening nvidia-settings, but none of my experimental alterations to any of the settings has made a difference.

I can still use my computer, but it seems to break the themes, icons, and styles so my computer looks like Unix circa 1992, which is a pretty annoying.

How do I kill this error?

Comment: I Have not .config to remove But [This answer worked with me](http://askubuntu.com/a/888115/612958)
http://askubuntu.com/a/888115/612958

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
rm $HOME/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: For some reason, I don't even have the .config direcotory/and monitors.xml file. I still have this problem still. If I click OK, everything goes and works exactly as planned and all the normal visuals are back. i still want to get rid of that annoying popup though

Comment: you will need a directory .config regardless

Comment: Had this problem in Linux Mint and Ubuntu using a VM, now working after deleting this conf file :)

Comment: @user37327: Folders and Files that start with a dot (".") are considered hidden and you have to set some option in your file browser to see them.

Comment: Can I prevent this file from being created automatically? It's rather annoying to have to delete it every time.