# Installing graphics driver to fix resolution using vga to a 23 inch hd flat screen, ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, display-resolution, lspci

So I've broken my Ubuntu on my laptop (Lenovo Z580). I've got stuck in a login reboot, black screen or error messages on startup. So I've deleted the partition and reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit), using a DVD that I had, with download 3rd party software ticked. I have updated and upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 (64bit). Did not install anything else yet and no errors as of yet.

When I'm on Windows, when I plug my laptop into my Samsung 23 inch screen using my VGA cable it works perfectly, but on Ubuntu the resolution is not correct and only 2 resolutions are present in the setting of the flat screen.

I've used `lspci | grep VGA` to find the GPU card's model:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
```

So I have a `GeForce GT 635M` graphics card. At this moment I am guessing that an Intel Corporation driver is running. Does this mean that the CPU is doing the work at the moment?

So i'm at this website that tells me how to install the driver that support my graphics card.
[WEBSITE](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2015/11/install-nvidia-linux-display-driver_22.html)

Instructions to download driver

```
For 32bit:
$ wget -c http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/358.16/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-358.16.run

For 64bit:
$ wget -c http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/358.16/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-358.16.run
```

Instructions to set permissions to downloaded script to be able to run it

```
$ sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-*-358.16.run
```

Then before I run the install script I need to do the following: (Kill certain processes)

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/kdm stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mdm stop
```

Then finally run the script

```
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-*-358.16.run
```

Will this process not give me that black screen at login?

Will there be more resolutions for my flat screen?

**I'm just asking this question, because I don't want to mess up drivers and really want my HD resolution to work using VGA**. I did try manually add resolutions, but screens starts to flicker and then I needed to unplug my monitor every time or reset my laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: @Zacharee1 So I must just try to do it and hope it works? If it does not I should do the suggestions in that link?

Comment: No, you should follow the directions in that link, as they will most likely solve your original problem.

Comment: @Zacharee I'm currently doing the fix, following your advise. It says that in will install the following additional packages:  bbswitch-dkms dkms lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libcuda1-364 libjansson4 libxnvctrl0
  nvidia-opencl-icd-364 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1
  screen-resolution-extra. I note that the last package is screen resolution extra, will that fix my resolututions?(I'm downloading still)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my fix. With the help of Zacharee1.

I've installed the driver using the terminal commands under the heading **Now for the fix** on this website [Zacharee1 answer on a website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) (No errors)

But no luck with resolutions being automatically there. I think an HDMI cable is to be expected. So trying to add a resolution manually to VGA-1 works nicely now.

Commands to add a resolution:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

So basically I save this commands in a file and need to run it every time in a terminal when the pc booted. There are other ways!

When I got errors shown on this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67337/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-monitor-error) I removed the monitors.xml file

```
rm /home/user_name/.config/monitors.xml
```

Everything is working for me now. My flat screen is showing HD xD

Comment: I get this error when executing last command "xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-1"

Answer (score 1):

> I get this error when executing last command "xrandr: cannot find
>   output "VGA-1" – ScottF Jan 3 '17 at 2:09

That is because the 'VGA-1' monitor doesn't exist. To check your monitors type:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

and write the correct monitor, in my case VGA1.