# Ubuntu Stuck on display Dialog after reboot

Tags: 14.04, display, virtualization

I changed my screen resolution on my Ubuntu vm.

After reboot the OS is hang on a dialog saying

> COULD NOT LOAD STORED CONFIGURATION FOR MONITORS

I've read through forums and found a solution that helped others, removing or renaming `~/.config/xorg.conf` file, but I can't seem to edit the file as I have booted in safe mode.

Comment: `rm $HOME/.config/monitors.xml` should reset the display settings to default. See [How do I get rid of this monitor error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67337/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-monitor-error).

Comment: I do not find monitors.xml in my config folder ,, is there a possibility the monitors.xml file lives somewhere else ?